# Knowing which application tries to unlock a GNOME Keyring

Tags: password, keyrings, gnome-keyring, keys

Sometimes, I see a dialog asking for the unlock password of the GNOME Keyring.

This dialog doesn't tell me anything about the application which wants to access the keyring secrets. Thus,I would like to know if is possible to get any information which can help to identify it.

I **don't** like to know how to disable the password dialog, but rather how to know which application is causing it, in order to uninstall it.

Comment: This site is pretty much English only, so can you translate this into English as best you can?

Comment: @jdv: now it's translated, sorry.

Comment: I told him to ask here at AskUbuntu so I would translate the question, but I had to be away from keyboard since 17:00 hours. I think that the question is pretty valid once translated.

Comment: @NickTux: Effectively, the linked question seems to be a duplicate or nearly duplicate... but we're on 2018 and there isn't a satisfactory answer yet. **:-(**

Comment: It seems like this problem is very deep into the rabbit hole, and there isn't yet a general solution.